BlackBox opimization with Bayesian Optimization
I would like to use Bayesian Optimization to identify new interesting parameters for my physics experiments.
More specifically, I want to initialize the algorithm with known bounded experimental parameters and use Bayesian optimization to do a black-box optimization. I am currently working on Python with a library called “bayes_op”, however, all the examples I found make use of a mathematically defined function.
I would like to start by giving the score of the function on some experimental points to begin the algorithm and then obtain a suggestion of the next interesting experimental parameters.
So far, I have succeeded in optimizing known functions starting with random parameters. However, I would like to know if it is possible to use this algorithm without providing an explicit function, while leveraging already available experimental data. I would like to add that I do not have a dataset to train anything.

This question is too broad for as a programming question. You are more likely to get suggestions over at Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/
